# Передача файла на API с помощью JQuery в IE9-

Tags: jquery, api, internet-explorer

Имеется следующий код страницы:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>.
<html language="ru">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<script src="jquery-2.1.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="respond.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<script type="text/javascript">
    function upload_file(this_) {
        var send_url = $(this_).attr('data-url');
        var send_file = new FormData();                 //1
        send_file.append('userpic', this_.files[0]);    //2
        console.log(send_file);
        $.ajax({
            url: send_url,
            type: "POST",
            data: send_file,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            succes: function () {
                alert('uploaded');
            },
            error: function (x, y, z) {
                alert(x + '\n' + y + '\n' + z);
            }
        });
    };
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input class="fileinput" data-url="my-url" name="userpic" type="file" onchange="upload_file(this)"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Данный код отправляет файл, который выбрал пользователь в input-file, на API по адресу "my-url". Проблема заключается только в том, что я не могу выбрать файл в IE9 и ниже, т.к. не поддерживается свойство file. То есть ругается на строчки 1 и 2.
Как можно данную проблему устранить?

P.S. Что происходит с файлом на стороне сервера - задача для другого человека, мне же ему надо отправить файл. На сервере располагается проект с WebAPI

Answer (score 1):

Предлагается пользовать полифилы, которые эмулируют это через флеш/сильверлайт/как-то еще: [раздел File API](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills)

Comment: и какой полифил тогда использовать в конкретном случае?

Comment: Я бы видимо стал ковыряться с https://github.com/mailru/FileAPI и тамошним upload(), а так слава богу поддерживать ie9- уже не приходится, упокой их всех господь.

Comment: Я бы тоже с радостью от них отказался, но увы... Ковыряние в тамошнего upload() не дало результата в IE8. А битовую карту не получается в том же браузере сделать...